# Google firestore NotFound exception doesn't get caught

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

It seems that the datasnapshot `game_doc` is not null (None) and so the first ***if*** statement gets through successfully and inside the if, when I call the method `to_dict()` on my datasnapshot, another different exception gets called: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` This exception gets thrown at  the second ***if*** which checks the field 'updated_at'

```
try:
    # exists
    game_doc = db.collection(u'games').document(str(game['id'])).get()
    if game_doc is not None:
        game_dict = game_doc.to_dict()
        if game_dict['updated_at'] != game['updated_at']:
            # update
            print("Updating game")
            add_game(game)
except google.cloud.exceptions.NotFound:
    # add
    print("Adding game")
    add_game(game)
```

`google.cloud.exceptions.NotFound` is never caught and the ***games*** collection doesn't exist in my firestore database

Comment: Can you post the error you are receiving, or is it the TypeError you already posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore in Python returns generators which are created after the request from the client is received and happens both when querying a single document or many. The google.cloud.exceptions.NotFound may be returned on certain APIs that return one and only one object. Possibly what you are looking for is:

```
try:
    game_doc = db.collection(u'games').document(str(game['id'])).get()
    game_dict = game_doc.to_dict()
    # exists
    if game_dict is not None:
        if game_dict['updated_at'] != game['updated_at']:
            # update
            print("Updating game")
            add_game(game)
    else:
        # add
        print("Adding game")
        add_game(game)
except:
    # Handle Other Exceptions.
```

To know more about [generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)): "*A generator is very similar to a function that returns an array, in that a generator has parameters, can be called, and generates a sequence of values. However, **instead of building an array** containing all the values and returning them all at once, a generator yields the values one at a time, which requires less memory and allows the caller to get started processing the first few values immediately*"